# 2D Slope Exceptions C#

Tags: c#, math, computational-geometry

I have the basic method for finding slope in 2D Space with the following code (C#)

```
    public static double Slope(Curve line)
    {
        double x1 = line.StartPoint.X;
        double y1 = line.StartPoint.Y;
        double x2 = line.EndPoint.X;
        double y2 = line.EndPoint.Y;

        double m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);

        return m;
    }
```

My question is what can I do to get around the [DivideByZeroException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dividebyzeroexception?view=net-5.0)? If the difference of X-Values is 0, of course execution will stop.

Is there a better way to handle this exception other than adding a try catch? Or maybe even a better approach to representing the slope of a line computationally?

My primary purpose for using this Slope method is simply to identify whether the given line is Vertical or Horizontal.

Comment: doubles divided by zero e.g. `100.0 / 0.0` gives `Double.PositiveInfinity` IIRC. From your link, _`DivideByZeroException` is "The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to divide an integral or `Decimal` value by zero."_ https://dotnetfiddle.net/O071VD

Comment: Just check if `x1 == x2` and handle that case appropriately?

Comment: I guess the simplest way is to check whether the values are zero with a simple if stament.

Comment: @DawidWawrzynczyk This can easily be done, but how do I differentiate a difference of X-Values that equals 0 from a difference of Y-Values that equals 0. My goal is to decide whether the line is vertical or horizontal

Comment: @wisenickel you're overthinking it. `Double` division automatically takes care of +-Infinities for you. Even if you don't want to rely on this, `x1 == x2` means the line is vertical and has an infinite slope. `y1 == y2` means the line is horizontal and has _zero_ slope. You won't have any division by zero in the latter case. `0 / anything` is zero.

Comment: @wisenickel do differenceY = y2 - y1 and differenceX = x2 - x1. Then if (differenceY == 0) {
    //Your code
}

Same for X difference if that is needed or just use else.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thank you I was unware that double division takes care of +- Infinities. I will implement this.

Comment: Why don't you just test x1 == x2 and y1 == y2 ? This is so much neater !

Comment: By the way, depending on the problem at hand, maybe you should worry about values close to zero, which may result in gross inaccuracies. Also consider using the implicit form of the line equation, which avoids these problems.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have never seen an implementation of the implicit form of a line equation, do you have any documentation I could reference?